# How to find UIImageView Path

Tags: iphone, ios

In my app I am taking a picture and showing it in an image view.

Now I need the path of that image so I can upload it to a server.

How do I get that path?  I try importing ALAsset framework but there is no framework called that my x code (4.2) iOS 5.0

```
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imagePic.image);
NSString *file = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"upload.jpg"];

[data writeToFile:file atomically:YES]; 

[[EPUploader alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myWebSite"]
                       filePath:@"file"
                       delegate:self
                   doneSelector:@selector(onUploadDone:)
                  errorSelector:@selector(onUploadError:)];
```

This is what I am currently trying.

Also what would be a hard coded path to a photo in an iphone camera roll?  "iphone/pictures/myPic" ??  so I can try the upload separate from finding the path.

Please and Thank you

**EDIT:**

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
// Access the uncropped image from info dictionary
image2 = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

// Save image
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image2, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
imagePic.image = image2;
[picker release];
}
```

Comment: wait why cant you just use the file variable that contains the path where you just saved the image?

Comment: you mean "file" for the nsdata of when i save it after i take the pic.  I really don't want to save the photo at all in the end but i can its no biggie

Comment: yeah that would work, you need to save it somewhere to have a path otherwise its only in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An image view has no path, it's in memory. You'll have to save the path you get when you return from taking the image. In the delegate method `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` you can get the `NSURL` in `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` which points to the image on disk:

```
NSURL *imageURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
```